# System.Runtime.CompilerServices in .NET Standard library

Tags: c#, .net-core

Currently I am in the process of converting a `.NET 4.5` class library to a `.NET Core` class library, referencing `.NETStandard v1.6`.

In part of my code (relying heavily on reflection) I need to determine whether an object is of type [`Closure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.closure(v=vs.110).aspx), which is located in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace. This namespace and type is not available in `.NETStandard v1.6`.

- Did this type move, or is it no longer accessible?
- Since my code relied on it, what is an alternative in case it is not available in `.NETStandard`?

The specific code relying on `Closure` determines the parameter types of a delegate, skipping the compiler generated `Closure` ones.

```
Delegate toWrap;
MethodInfo toWrapInfo = toWrap.GetMethodInfo();
var toWrapArguments = toWrapInfo.GetParameters()
    // Closure argument isn't an actual argument, but added by the compiler.
   .SkipWhile( p => p.ParameterType == typeof( Closure ) )
   .Select( p => p.ParameterType );
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the type, where you know it is a `Closure` or similar, while using an old .net framework version? After having the type you might have good chances to find a corresponding class (somehow connected to your type) in the object catalog in visual studio.

Comment: @ChrisTophski I'm on it. Once my migrated code compiles I will run my tests and see what changed. In case nobody else has answered this question by then, I will. ;p

Comment: Use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @LexLi Seemingly no hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net Core 1.0, [`Closure` exists in the `System.Linq.Expressions` assembly in the `System.Linq.Expressions` package](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.0.0/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/Closure.cs), but it's not exposed in a reference assembly. This means it's just an implementation detail in Core (and could for example vanish or move in a future version). It also means you can't reference it at compile time (like you did in .Net Framework), but you can retrieve it using reflection at runtime (don't forget `using System.Reflection;` for `GetTypeInfo()`):

```
Type closureType = typeof(Expression).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
    .GetType("System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure");
```

In .Net Framework, `Closure` is in a different assembly (namely, `System.Core`), but so is `Expression`, so this code should work on both.

Comment: In that case, for the purpose of the code listed I presume I am just as well off simply checking the `FullName` of the type, since retrieving the type through reflection relies on the exact same dependency. Regardless, this answers the question.